# Being able to read a .dat in English, and then being able to edit the file

Tags: java

```
        File file = new File(directory + player.getUsername() + ".dat");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
        DataOutputStream write = new DataOutputStream(outFile);
        write.writeUTF(player.getUsername());
        write.writeUTF(player.getPassword());
        write.writeInt(player.getStaffRights());
        write.writeInt(player.getPosition().getX());
        write.writeInt(player.getPosition().getY());
        write.writeInt(player.getPosition().getZ());
        write.writeInt(player.getGender());
```

Ok so pretty much what this code above does is it makes new character files for this game im working with. But the problem im having is that the character information that this code is putting into a .dat I cant read when I try and open in lets say notepad its just gibberish. I need to be able to open these .dats and be able to read/edit the text in english. Any help?

Comment: Store the data as strings, not as binary.

Comment: zubergu how would i go about doing that?

Comment: How are you currently persisting the data as binary? How could you change this to text?

Answer (score 0):

When you save data with a `DataOutputStream`, it will be saved in Java's native binary serialization format, not as plain text which you can read with for example Notepad.

If you want to write plain text to a file, use one of the subclasses of `java.io.Writer` to write to the file instead of `DataOutputStream` - for example `PrintWriter`.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);
out.println(player.getUsername());
// etc...

// Also, don't forget to close when you are done
out.close();
```

Comment: would i be able to change it to PrintWriter from DataOutputStream and then all future character files would be saved as text in the .dat?

Comment: @user1601916 Yes, try it out for yourself and see what happens.

Comment: ok so do I use the PrintWriter to write data to the file and how would i do that? PrintWriter.println(player.getUsername()); ?

Comment: Did you look at my answer above? It shows exactly how to do it. Remove the two lines with `FileOutputStream` and `DataOutputStream` and replace it with `PrintWriter`.

Answer (score -1):

Have the player object implement Serilizable and as long as all of its properties are serilizable as well, such as strings and ints, the serialization will be done.

Refer to the serialization tutorial:

[Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)

Comment: That will not make the file readable with a text editor, which is what the user asked for.